# Proxy linked material

Tags: materials, node-editor, linked-data

I am linking a large scene into another file. The scene consists of lots of objects and lights. All of the lights use the same material group, but it has a different output for each light. This lets me easily control their emission strength all from the same location.

What I want is to Link the whole scene into a new file, but then still be able to adjust the strengths of the lights, but for that file only. To do this I need to somehow have access to the Nodegroup that they all use.

I can make proxies of specific objects to change their settings for that file only, but is there a way to do this for materials/nodes?

Comment: You can alter certain nodes, after they are linked. I know for sure, that this is possible for RGB Curves for example. I'd suggest you build a fast testing scene, with just one object and shader, and drop in math and value nodes to see, which ones can be altered and are able to drive the strengh oft your emission.